# How cain i use SWC with MUI?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, babeljs, swc

I started a proyect in vite using vite, when i stared to @mui/material i started to have problems with babel.

I found out that that some people had that problem, because the version of babel they had and the one that MUI required where different, so i tried changing version and didn't work.

At the end the only thing that i think i could  be i that swc is incompatible with MUI.

With that conclusion in mind, i tried ways to make it work but no one has any answer for something even near to that.

This were the errors i got:

- Could not resolve "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends"
  import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends"
- Could not resolve "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectWithoutPropertiesLoose"
  ...PropertiesLoose from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectWithoutPropertiesLoose"
  and others like that.